# How can i intergral the I and solve it?

Tags: calculus

> Compute the integral
> $$
> I=\int_1^{+\infty}\left[\frac{1}{t}-\operatorname{arcsinh} \frac{1}{t}\right] \mathrm{d} t\,.
> $$

So far, I obtain
\begin{align} I & =\int_1^{+\infty}\left[\frac{1}{t}-\operatorname{arcsinh} \frac{1}{t}\right] \mathrm{d} t \\ 
& =\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{t} d t-\int_1^{\infty} \operatorname{arcsinh} \frac{1}{t} \cdot \mathrm{d} t \\ 
& =\left.\ln(t)\right|_1 ^{\infty}-\int_1^{\infty} \operatorname{arcsinh} \frac{1}{t} \cdot \mathrm{d} t \\ & =\infty-\int_1^{\infty} \operatorname{arcsinh}\left(\frac{1}{t}\right) \cdot \mathrm{d} t\,,
\end{align}
but I don’t know how to compute the second part.

Comment: Do you know the trick for integrating $\ln(x)$? Try applying that here.

Comment: As a side note, you can't take the limit to infinity until you've integrated both parts. Otherwise you could get $\infty - \infty$ when the answer is actually a finite number.

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this integral, you'll have to use mainly integration by parts.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_1^\infty\left(\frac{1}{t}-\text{arcsinh}\frac{1}{t}\right)\text dt&=\left[\ln t\right|_1^\infty-\int_1^\infty\text{arcsinh}\frac{1}{t}\ \text dt\\
&\overset{(\ast)^1}{=}\left[\ln t\right|_1^\infty-\left(\left[t\text{arcsinh}\frac{1}{t}\right|_1^\infty+\int_1^\infty\frac{\text dt}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)\\
&\overset{(\ast)^2}{=}\left[\ln t-t\text{arcsinh}\frac{1}{t}-\text{arcsinh}\ t\right|_1^\infty\\
&=\lim_{t\to\infty}\left(\ln t-t\text{arcsinh}\frac{1}{t}-\text{arcsinh}\ t\right)+2\text{arcsinh}\ 1\\
&=\lim_{t\to\infty}\left(\ln t-t\left(\frac{1}{t}+...\right)-\ln(t+\sqrt{t^2+1})\right)+2\text{arcsinh}\ 1\\
&=2\text{arcsinh}\ 1-1+\lim_{t\to\infty}\ln\left(\frac{t}{t+\sqrt{t^2+1}}\right)=2\text{arcsinh}\ 1-1-\ln\ 2\approx0.0696
\end{aligned}
$$

---

$(\ast)^1:$ Here I chose $u=\text{arcsinh}\frac{1}{t}$ and $\text dv=\text dt$, thus, since $\text{arcsinh}x=\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})$,
$$\left\{
\begin{aligned}
&\text du=\frac{\text d(1/t)}{\text dt}\frac{\text d\text{ arcsinh}(1/t)}{\text d(1/t)}\text dt=\frac{-\text dt}{t\sqrt{1+t^2}}\\
&v=t
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
Finally, you substitute the relations here:
$$\int_1^\infty u\text dv=[uv|_1^\infty-\int_1^\infty v\text du$$

$(\ast)^2:$ The integral is easily solvable doing $t=\sinh t'$:
$$\int_1^\infty\frac{\text dt}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}=\int_{t=1}^{t\to\infty}\frac{\cosh t'\text dt'}{\sqrt{1+\sinh^2t'}}=\int_{t=1}^{t\to\infty}\text dt'=[t'|_{t=1}^{t\to\infty}=\left[\text{arcsinh}\ t\right|_1^\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

By IBP
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\int\left[\frac{1}{t}-\operatorname{arcsinh} \frac{1}{t}\right] \mathrm{d} t\\
&=&t\left[\frac{1}{t}-\operatorname{arcsinh} \frac{1}{t}\right]-\int\bigg(-\frac1t+\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}\bigg)\mathrm{d} t\\
&=&1-t\operatorname{arcsinh}(\frac1t)+\ln t-\operatorname{arcsinh}(t)
\end{eqnarray}$$
$$ I=1-t\operatorname{arcsinh}(\frac1t)+\ln t-\operatorname{arcsinh}(t)\bigg|_1^\infty=-1-\log (2)+2 \operatorname{arcsinh}(1).$$